# Binding Bit Flags To checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, enums, checkbox

I have ten checkboxes and Enum.
I want to bind this checkboxes to Enum.
The problem is that there is a lot of consistency of the code.

```
public partial class RightsSetForm : Form
    {
        public RightsEnum rights;
        public int count = 1;
        public RightsSetForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            rights |= RightsEnum.notify;
        }

        private void chkNotify_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (chkNotify.Checked)
            {
                rights |= RightsEnum.notify;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                rights ^= RightsEnum.notify;
                count--;
            }
        }

        private void chkFriends_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkFriends.Checked)
            {
                count++;
                rights |= RightsEnum.friends;
            }
            else
            {
                rights ^= RightsEnum.friends;
                count--;
            }
        }
}
```

Is it possible to simplify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Control.Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property to store the enum value for each checkbox, and use a common `CheckedChanged` event handler:

```
chkFriends.Tag = RightsEnum.friends;
chkNotify.Tag = RightsEnum.notify;

chkFriends.CheckedChanged += enumCheckedChanged;
chkNotify.CheckedChanged += enumCheckedChanged;
```

The common event handler receives the `Checkbox` as `sender`, and it can extract the enum value from `Tag`:

```
void enumCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkbox = (Checkbox)sender;

    var flag = (RightsEnum)checkbox.Tag;

    if (checkbox.Checked)
    {
        count++;
        rights |= flag;
    }
    else
    {
        rights ^= flag;
        count--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution.  I always forget about the Tag object.

Answer (score 2):

You could have one event handler you assign to each checkbox that casts the sender as CheckBox and then switch statements on the Name property (which is the label of the CheckBox) to select the enum.  Something like:

```
private void checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;

    RightsEnum rightsEnum = RightsEnum.notify;
    switch (checkBox.Name)
    {
        case "chkNotify":
            rightsEnum = RightsEnum.notify;
            break;
        case "chkFriends":
            rightsEnum = RightsEnum.friends;
            break;    
        // to do:  add the remaining 8       
    }

    if (checkBox.Checked)
    {
         count++;
         rights |= rightsEnum;
    }
    else
    {
         rights ^= rightsEnum;
         count--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inmx has a good start, though he did miss a few things.

```
private void enumCheckedChanged(Checkbox pBox, bool pbAddFirst) {
    if (!(pBox.Tag is RightsEnum)) return;

    RightsEnum flag = pBox.Tag as RightsEnum;

    if (pBox.Checked && pbAddFirst) {
         count++;
         rights |= flag;
    }
    else if (pBox.Checked && !pbAddFirst) {
         rights |= flag;
         count++;
    }
    // Having checked for both variations of pbAddFirst, the only thing left would be if pBox.Checked is false
    else {
         rights ^= flag;
         count--;
    }
}
```

If you happen to need to subtract the count first, you can always modify the else with pbAddFirst again.

then in the Check event for each CheckBox, you'd just have the method call:

```
private void chkFriends_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    enumCheckedChanged(chkFriends, true);
}
```

It's definitely a good call to use the Tag property of the Checkbox.  That will make your life a lot easier if you tie your data objects to your UI objects.